# how to Import quickbooks desktop data to mysql using php

Tags: php, quickbooks

I want to import quickbooks desktop data(i.e customers, invoices) to mysql database, 
when i tried to add an application via quick books web connector by given .qwc file(example_web_connector_import.php)

i am getting an error code(QBWC1039) and says in log file "QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
"

In the "example_web_connector_import.php" file i given user name pass for quickbooks. is it correct? or i have to give web connector credentials?

Can any one aware of it,if so how to fix this issue?

regards
Narendra.

Answer (score 0):

> QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.

So did you check your QWCLog.txt for details?

What did the log say? You can view the log at any time by clicking the "View Log" button, or opening the file in Notepad.

Post the relevant sections of the log if you need more help with that.

> In the "example_web_connector_import.php" file i given user name pass for quickbooks. is it correct?

No.

If you read the comments in the example code, they very specifically indicate:

```
// A username and password you'll use in: 
//  a) Your .QWC file
//  b) The Web Connector
//  c) The QuickBooks framework
//
//  NOTE: This has *no relationship* with QuickBooks usernames, Windows usernames, etc. 
//      It is *only* used for the Web Connector and SOAP server!
```

This username/password is stored in the `quickbooks_user` SQL table. You can edit them at any time in that table.

Make sure the username you used in the .QWC file matches what's in the SQL table.

> or i have to give web connector credentials?

Correct, you have to give the Web Connector credentials. See my notes above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LetSync Desktop for it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).